# problem of cell assignment in a pandas dataframe using df.at method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHpi5.png)

and I would to change the value of the cell at the row index 11 and the column name K1L.
To do so, I write
`index_quadrupole = df[df['NAME']=="H01_EMQ_01"].index.values.astype(int)[0]`

in order to get the index of the row.

Then I use the method df.at
`df.at[index_quadrupole, "K1L"]=4.0`

I get an error message:
print(df.at[11, "K1L"]=4.0)
^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

When I print print(df.at[11, "K1L"]), I get the right value.
I don't want to return True or False, I would like to change the value of the cell in the dataframe.
What do I do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Think the issue is trying to `print` your assignment statement. If you just want to change the cell value, just use the `df.at[...] = ...` and then if you want to confirm the change, then `print(df.at[...])` afterwards.

Comment: I feel ashame. Thank you very very much